# How can i have file upload with editable textbox mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium, c#-4.0

My QA team want to use file upload textbox as editable how can i achieve this?

[image]

using below code i can get this above browse button which is not editable textbox where we can see that file path.

QA team want to set file path automatically using selenium tool but as its a file control they are not able to set file path.

any solution for this ?

current code works fine -

Home.cshtml

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
     if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
     {
         var file = Request.Files[0];

         if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
         {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
         }
     }

     return RedirectToAction("UploadDocument");
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean _file upload textbox as editable_?

Comment: You cannot set the value of a file input for security reasons

Comment: so how can i achieve this ? any other control  ? because QA team they are unable to make it automatic.
Can i do work around like take a txtbox and copy filepath into txtbox and read file in backend using that path value instead use

Comment: May be 2nd and 3rd answers in  [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test) will help